# Visual Studio - Teams Project Issue

Tags: visual-studio, teams-toolkit

I created a Visual Studio project to create a Teams Plugin. I was able to get it created but I have constantly faced an issue where I get stuck with this error - "Error: Visual Studio seems to be doing something but fails with the following error "The dev tunnel with the name '' is not set to public access. Please use a public dev tunnel in the debug dropdown menu (Dev Tunnels) to prepare Teams app."

I figure that this has something to do with preparing teams app dependencies. When I try to do that, it fails with an error when trying to connect to my personal 365 account.

I have tried to mess with settings and ensure that Nuget packages are up to date.

Has anyone faced this issue before and have any recommendations?

Answer (score 0):

To debug the bot in a local environment, you'll need to utilize a public development tunnel to manage requests. You can create a new public development tunnel in Visual Studio by selecting 'Dev Tunnels' from the debug dropdown menu, then choosing 'Create A Tunnel' (and setting the authentication type to Public). And use this tunnel to prepare Teams app and debug.

[image]

[image]